# Query SQL Server for JOIN and WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with my SQL query.

I want to join 2 tables, with condition using where `id_pegawai` and `status = 1`.

Table 1:

```
SELECT * FROM form_pertambahan_anak
```

[image]

Table 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM peg_dtl_anak 
WHERE id_pegawai = '0000000360'
```

[image]

My query:

```
SELECT  
    fpa.id_pegawai, fpa.tanggal_pengusulan, fpa.id_anak, 
    pda.id, pda.nama_anak, fpa.deleted_at, fpa.status
FROM    
    form_pertambahan_anak fpa 
INNER JOIN 
    peg_dtl_anak pda ON pda.id_pegawai = fpa.id_pegawai
WHERE 
    fpa.id_pegawai = '0000000360' 
    AND fpa.deleted_at IS NULL 
    AND fpa.status = '1'
```

[image]

Why return 2 rows of data? 1 expect just showing 1 data from `form_pertambahan_anak` with `status = 1`.

Comment: It returns two rows because both match all conditions you've set. It seems like you need to add a further condition: form_pertambahan_anak.id_anak = peg_dtl_anak.id;

Comment: Please, do not use images!

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you need to add an id_anak equality condition to the query:

```
SELECT fpa.id_pegawai
     , fpa.tanggal_pengusulan
     , fpa.id_anak
     , pda.id
     , pda.nama_anak
     , fpa.deleted_at
     , fpa.status
  FROM form_pertambahan_anak fpa
  INNER JOIN peg_dtl_anak pda ON pda.id_pegawai = fpa.id_pegawai
                             AND pda.id = fpa.id_anak --here
WHERE fpa.id_pegawai = '0000000360'
  AND fpa.deleted_at IS NULL
  AND fpa.status = '1'
```